# MySql Select where row count is 2

Tags: mysql, sql, querying

I have a table called frequents with 2 columns, drinkers and the bars they frequent.

I currently have answered this statement:

```
 Drinkers who frequent at least 2 bars
```

With the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT drinker
FROM frequents f
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT drinker
FROM frequents y
WHERE y.drinker=f.drinker
AND f.bar<>y.bar);
```

I am trying to modify this query to answer the following:

```
Drinkers who frequent exactly two bars
```

but I am stuck as to what modifications to my logic must be implemented to satisfy this statement.

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of drinkers where they have 2 rows in the table, group by drinker and then using having to get where count is 2:

```
SELECT drinker
  FROM frequents
  GROUP BY drinker
HAVING COUNT(drinker) = 2
```